# Display data in Column using LWC

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components

I am trying to create a view to show activity information. However the below code is not displaying any information, only header is showing. Please help.

**HTML Component :**

```
<template>
    <lightning-card class="slds-text-title_bold"  title = "Activity Information">
        <div class="slds-p-around_medium lgc-bg" style="height: 300px;">
            <lightning-datatable
                    key-field="id"
                    data={data}
                    columns={columns}>
            </lightning-datatable>
        </div>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

**JS File:**

```
import { LightningElement,api,wire,track} from 'lwc';
import ActivitySearchController from '@salesforce/apex/ActivityLeadPage.ActivitySearchController'

const columns = [
    { label: 'Subject', fieldName: 'Subject' },
    { label: 'Due Date', fieldName: 'ActivityDate' },
    { label: 'Status', fieldName: 'Status' },
];

export default class ActivityLeadPageComponent extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;
    @track data = [];
    @track columns = columns;
    @wire(ActivitySearchController, { currentID: '$recordID'})
    TaskList;
}
```

**Controller :**

```
public class ActivityLeadPage{

    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<Task> ActivitySearchController(String currentID){
        List<Task> TaskList = new List<Task>();
        Map<Id,Lead> leadMap = new Map<Id,Lead>();
        if(currentID.startsWith('00Q')){
            try{
                List <Lead> leadList = [SELECT id, Email FROM Lead WHERE ID=:currentId];
                String ldEmail       = leadList[0].Email;
                Set<String> emailIds = new Set<string>();
                if(ldEmail!=null){
                    emailIds.add(ldEmail);
                }               

                TaskList = getTaskList(emailIds);

            }           
            catch(Exception e){
                system.debug('getlinenumber-->'+ e.getMessage() +' line '+ e.getLineNumber());
            } 
        }
        return TaskList;
    }

    public static List<Task> getTaskList (Set<String> emailIds) {  
        Map<Id,Lead> leadMap = new Map<Id,Lead>();      
        leadMap = new Map<Id,Lead>([SELECT id, Email FROM Lead Where Email IN:emailIds]);       

        Set<Id> leadID = new Set<Id>(); 
        for(Lead lE : leadMap.values()){
            leadID.add(lE.id);            
        }  

        List<Task> TaskList = [Select id, Subject, Description, who.Type, What.Type, Priority, Status, ActivityDate,CreatedDate, LastModifiedDate FROM Task 
                               WHERE whoId IN:leadID ORDER BY createddate DESC LIMIT 20];

        if(TaskList.size() == 0){
            Apexpages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.INFO,''+'No Tasks to Display'));
        }

        return TaskList;
    }   
}
```

Comment: pls use `{}` for code formatting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because you are not setting data. Do following in wire service:

```
@wire(ActivitySearchController, { currentID: '$recordID'})
TaskList({ data, error }) {
    if (data) {
        this.data = data;
    } else if (error) {
        console.error("ERROR ", error);
    }
}
```

Also you are not using correct data type for date in columns (by default its `text`)

```
{ label: 'Due Date', fieldName: 'ActivityDate', type: 'date' },
```

You can use `typeAttributes` also to customize whether you need just date or datetime and also how each property (date,month etc) has to be rendered.